# Login Form Save Password Getting Mixed With Sign up Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

hi guys i just needed a little help actually i have created two forms inside one page but now the problem is when i save password for login the same save password and id show on my sign up form and it's very irritating any solution to patch that up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a code, so we can see what's exactly going on...

Comment: Have you saved that on your login page?

Comment: are you using same id or what ? to know what is the problem please provide your code.

Comment: I was using the same name that was the issue thanks for your response and sorry for my late response